# Nested function with Core Data

Tags: function, core-data, swiftui

SwiftUI newbie here :-)

I have a Core Data entity, "Cars", with the following attributes:

```
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var uses: Int16
    @NSManaged public var cost: Int16
    @NSManaged public var type: String
```

I'm trying to print out the average cost per use for each type of car (by which I mean, for example, how many times all VWs was used, divided by total cost of all VWs, divided by total count of VWs).

I've managed to group the cars into types with the function `group`:

```
func group(_ result : FetchedResults<Cars>)-> [[Cars]] {
        
    return Dictionary(grouping: result) { $0.type }
            .sorted(by: {$0.key < $1.key})
            .map {$0.value}
        
    }
```

However, now I'm struggling to create an array which holds the average for each type.

I've tried adding this function, but get the message "Cannot find 'av' in scope":

```
func andAv (cars: [[Cars]]) -> [Int] {
    
    
    ForEach(cars, id: \.self) { i in
        
        let sumCost = i.map { Int($0.cost) }.reduce(0,+)
        let sumUses = i.map { Int($0.uses) }.reduce(0,+)
        let itemCount = i.map { $0.id }.count
        let av = sumCost / sumUses / itemCount
    }
    
    return [av]
    
}
```

I think maybe I need to be using a nested function?

As I mention, I'm a beginner and SwiftUI is my first programming language, so perhaps I'm missing something very obvious or making a silly mistake. In either case, any help hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForEach` is a SwiftUI type which is for creating views based on a collection of data. You're not interested in views at this point.

```
func andAv (cars: [[Cars]]) -> [Int] {
    
    let averages: [Int] = cars.map { i in
        
        let sumCost = i.map { Int($0.cost) }.reduce(0,+)
        let sumUses = i.map { Int($0.uses) }.reduce(0,+)
        let itemCount = i.count
        let av = sumCost / sumUses / itemCount
        return av
    }
    
    return averages
    
}
```

You should also address the points in vadian's answer regarding integers and Core Data types, but your fundamental problem is that `ForEach` is for building views, not for processing data.

Comment: Thanks, super helpful! I thought that might be the case. I am also sure that there are a few issues as per Vadian's reponse. N.b. when I try your code I get this error: "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate". Making a slight change solved this: "let averages: [Int] = cars.map { i in". Do you want to make this edit in your response so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: I updated the answer. It was browser code so I didn't check if it compiled before I posted, sorry

Comment: No need to be sorry. This was hugely helpful- many thanks!